# Multiple click on a button in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to perform multiple clicks on a button (4 times) in selenium webdriver, without making use of for loop?
Currently I have to make use of for loop to click on a button and make it work because on a single click it doesn't work.

Any solution for the above question?

```
for (int i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='body']/div[6]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a")).click();
}

Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='body']/div[6]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("7");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='body']/div[6]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("8");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='body']/div[6]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/input")).sendKeys("9");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='body']/div[6]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[7]/a/div[2]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("demobase")).click();
```

Comment: Why you do not want to use loop??

Comment: My question is why are you having to preform 4 clicks on a button?  How isnt a single click working? Why is the button visible in dom but not actionable? Is the button controlled by javascript?

Comment: I need to know if there are any commands that I can use instead of using loop.

Comment: I do not think so that any command available.

Comment: There is a much better solution i feel with some investigative work. I feel that before you go off writing unnecessary code such as a for loop that does nothing useful you need to better understand how that button is constructed and why it takes 4 clicks to respond. Your solution lies there. A for loop is a bandaid masking the real issue imo.

Answer (score 0):

Try For Java Script Executor

`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)); wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete")); IWebElement saveBtn = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Xpath("//*[@id='body']/div[6]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a"))); ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", saveBtn);`

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
WebElement we = findElement (By.xpath("path "));

Actions a = new Actions();
a.doubleClick(we).perform();
a.doubleClick(we).preform();
```

Comment: I tried using actions before also but it does not work, any other solution for the same.